# Menu list slightly going to the right side on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a menu which is left side company logo and right side menu list.

1) I am getting some issue when I hover on the contact us menu. It's slightly going to the right side when hovering because of the border.

2) What is the way to display a menu list in the center of the logo?

I am also sharing the link https://jsfiddle.net/Narendra2015/jmscoftq/

Would you help me out with this issue?

```css
#header_menu {
  background-color: #fff;
  /*position: fixed;top: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 900
}

#header_menu .main_header_menu {
  padding: 15px 50px;
}

#header_menu .main_header_menu .t_left_side_menu .t_header_logo {
  width: 200px;
}

#header_menu .main_header_menu .t_left_side_menu .t_header_logo img {
  width: 100%;
}

#header_menu .t_right_side_menu {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 60px;
}

#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li a {
  padding: 12px 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #343534
}

#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li a:hover {
  color: #00a2ff;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li a.btn_bg {
  color: #000;
}

#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li:last-child a {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li:last-child a:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: red;
  transition: 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<header id="header_menu">
  <div class="main_header_menu clearfix">
    <div class="t_left_side_menu pull-left">
      <div class="t_header_logo"><img src="http://1000logos.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/google-plus-logo.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
    <!--i_left_side-->

    <div class="t_right_side_menu pull-right">
      <div class="t_right_main_menu">
        <ul class="t_menu_list">
          <li><a href="">Hoem</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Service</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="contact_link btn_bg">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--right_side-->
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: instead all `#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li:last-child` you can simply use the class `.contact_link` in css

Comment: Thanks for the reply, That I will do. it's hard to tag you in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

1) To prevent the "moving" set border to `a` with  `transparent` color

2) **You use `vertical-align:middle;` what means you must use `display:inline block`**

so remove the classes `pull-right` and `pull-left` and set `display:inline block`
 to `.t_right_side_menu` and `.t_left_side_menu`

See here:https://jsfiddle.net/jmscoftq/10/

```css
#header_menu {
  background-color: #fff;
  /*position: fixed;top: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 900
}

#header_menu .main_header_menu {
  padding: 15px 50px;
}

#header_menu .main_header_menu .t_left_side_menu .t_header_logo {
  width: 200px;
}

#header_menu .main_header_menu .t_left_side_menu .t_header_logo img {
  width: 100%;
}
.t_left_side_menu{display: inline-block;}
#header_menu .t_right_side_menu {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 60px;
 display: inline-block;
}

#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li a {
  padding: 12px 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #343534
}

#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li a:hover {
  color: #00a2ff;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li a.btn_bg {
  color: #000;
}

#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li:last-child a {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li:last-child a:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: red;
  transition: 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<header id="header_menu">
  <div class="main_header_menu clearfix">
    <div class="t_left_side_menu">
      <div class="t_header_logo"><img src="http://1000logos.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/google-plus-logo.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
    <!--i_left_side-->

    <div class="t_right_side_menu">
      <div class="t_right_main_menu">
        <ul class="t_menu_list">
          <li><a href="">Hoem</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Service</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="contact_link btn_bg">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--right_side-->
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just want to know what you change and where you changed in my code?

Comment: `#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li:last-child a {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}`

Comment: Yeah!! it's solved my first issue. Can you help me out with the second one? How to display menu-list center of the logo

Comment: you have to make two steps:1)remove the class `pull-right` and `pull-left` from html 2) add in css `.t_left_side_menu , .t_right_side_menu{display: inline-block;}`
happy coding ;)

Comment: Yeah! I check your code but If I remove the pull-right than it will not display the menu on the right side.

Comment: what size of browser do you use(phone size,tablet,computer)?

Comment: It's a computer. Please check this screen shot http://prntscr.com/ktj5jh

Comment: There is no issue with the first solution but in a second answer, is not proper for me. My menu list is not fully on the right side like in my jsfiddle in the question. You can check the stack overflow website as well. It's like a logo and search on the left side and points and notification on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

-> resolve button hover & menu center of the logo please set following code into your existing code.

```css
#header_menu {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 900
}
#header_menu .main_header_menu {
  padding: 15px 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
#header_menu .main_header_menu .t_left_side_menu .t_header_logo {
  width: 200px;
}
#header_menu .main_header_menu .t_left_side_menu .t_header_logo img {
  width: 100%;
}
#header_menu .t_right_side_menu {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: right;
}
#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}
#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li a {
  padding: 12px 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #343534
}
#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li a:hover {
  color: #00a2ff;
  transition: 0.1s;
}
#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li a.btn_bg {
  color: #000;
}
#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li:last-child a {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li:last-child a:hover {
  border-color: red;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: red;
  transition: 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<header id="header_menu">
  <div class="main_header_menu clearfix">
    <div class="t_left_side_menu">
      <div class="t_header_logo"><img src="http://1000logos.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/google-plus-logo.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
    <!--i_left_side-->
    <div class="t_right_side_menu text-right">
      <div class="t_right_main_menu">
        <ul class="t_menu_list">
          <li><a href="">Hoem</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Service</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="contact_link btn_bg">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--right_side-->
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add transparent border for Anchor.**

Just add:

```
border:1px solid transparent;
```

to your css declaration:

```
#header_menu .t_right_side_menu ul.t_menu_list li:last-child a{text-transform: capitalize;border:1px solid transparent;}
```

Comment: My first issue got resolved in the first answer. What about the second issue? can you help me out in that